# mapping with an if statement based on data/class type

Tags: r, purrr

I have created a series of models which I would like to make predictions using new data. The code is the following:

The code below works but and is just put here to reproduce the data (but I do not have any question on this part of the code):

```
############## Pre-define some function ###########

logit2prob <- function(logit){
  odds <- exp(logit)
  prob <- odds / (1 + odds)
  return(prob)
}

###################################################

data(iris)
df <- iris %>% 
  filter(Species != "setosa") %>% 
  mutate(Species = +(Species == "virginica")) %>% 
  sample_n(10)

##########################################
var_combos <- expand.grid(colnames(df[,1:4]), colnames(df[,1:4])) %>% 
  filter(!Var1 == Var2)

boundary_lists <- map2(
  .x = var_combos$Var1,
  .y = var_combos$Var2,
  ~select(df, .x, .y) %>% 
    summarise(
      minX = min(.[[1]], na.rm = TRUE),
      maxX = max(.[[1]], na.rm = TRUE),
      minY = min(.[[2]], na.rm = TRUE),
      maxY = max(.[[2]], na.rm = TRUE)
      )
  ) %>% 
  map(.,
      ~tibble(
        x = seq(.x$minX, .x$maxX, length.out = 200),
        y = seq(.x$minY, .x$maxY, length.out = 200),
        )
      ) %>% 
  map(.,
      ~tibble(
        xx = rep(.x$x, each = 200),
        yy = rep(.x$y, time = 200)
        )
      ) %>% 
  map2(.,
       asplit(var_combos, 1), ~ .x %>% 
         set_names(.y))


xgboost(
  objective='binary:logistic',
  eval_metric = 'auc',
  data = as.matrix(df[, 1:2]),
  label = as.matrix(df[, 5]), # binary variable
  nrounds = 10
  )

models_list <- map2(
  var_combos$Var1,
  var_combos$Var2,
  ~df %>%
    select(Species, .x, .y) %>%
    group_by(grp = 'grp') %>% 
    nest() %>%
    mutate(
      models = map(
        data, 
        ~{
          list(
            glm(Species ~ ., data = .x, family = binomial(link='logit')),
            #e1071::svm(Species ~ ., data = .x,  type = 'C-classification', kernel = 'linear'),
            #randomForest::randomForest(formula = as.factor(Species) ~ ., data = .),
            xgboost(
              objective='binary:logistic',
              eval_metric = 'auc',
              data = as.matrix(df[, 1:2]),
              label = as.matrix(df[, 5]), # binary variable
              nrounds = 10
            )
            )
          }
        )
      )
  ) %>% 
  map(
    ., ~unlist(., recursive = FALSE)
    )
```

I now have a number of lists and models and the next step is to make predictions using the `predict()` function. However certain models require certain data structures. The `glm` model can take in a `data.frame` but the `xgboost` model requires a `matrix`.

If I remove the `xgboost` model in the `models_list` part of the code I can run the following:

```
models_predict <- models_list %>% 
  map(., pluck, 'models') %>% 
  map2(
    .x = .,
    .y = boundary_lists,
      ~predict(
        object = ., 
        newdata = .y
        )
    )
```

Which works, however when the `xgboost` model is in the list the code breaks since `xgboost` requires a `matrix`.

The following two `predict` functions work.

```
predict(
  object = models_list[[1]]$models[[1]],
  newdata = df[, 1:2]                       # for the glm model
  )

predict(
  object = models_list[[1]]$models[[2]],
  newdata = as.matrix(df[, 1:2]),           # for the xgboost model
  type = 'prob'
  )
```

How can I pass to the `map` function, conditions. I know of the conditional map `map_if()` function in `purrr` but I am not sure how to pass the conditions to it.

If the class = `xgb.Booster` then go to `predict_xgb` else `predict`.

```
models_list[[1]]$models[[1]] %>% attributes()
models_list[[1]]$models[[2]] %>% attributes()
```

I would like then to put the predictions into the same data frame list once the `predict` function has been applied.

EDIT:

In order to get multiple trained models I think I need to change the `models_list` part of the code to:

```
    models_list <- map2(
  var_combos$Var1,
  var_combos$Var2,
  ~df %>%
    select(Species, .x, .y) %>%
    group_by(grp = 'grp') %>% 
    nest() %>%
    mutate(
      models = map(
        data, 
        ~{
          list(
            glm(Species ~ ., data = .x, family = binomial(link='logit')),
            #e1071::svm(Species ~ ., data = .x,  type = 'C-classification', kernel = 'linear'),
            #randomForest::randomForest(formula = as.factor(Species) ~ ., data = .),
            xgboost(
              objective='binary:logistic',
              eval_metric = 'auc',
              data = as.matrix(.x[, 2:3]),
              label = as.matrix(.x$Species), # binary variable
              nrounds = 10
            )
          )
        }
      )
    )
) %>% 
  map(
    ., ~unlist(., recursive = FALSE)
  )
```

Then running:

```
models_list[[1]]$models[[2]]$feature_names
models_list[[2]]$models[[2]]$feature_names
models_list[[3]]$models[[2]]$feature_names
```

Gives me:

```
> models_list[[1]]$models[[2]]$feature_names
[1] "Sepal.Width"  "Sepal.Length"
> models_list[[2]]$models[[2]]$feature_names
[1] "Petal.Length" "Sepal.Length"
> models_list[[3]]$models[[2]]$feature_names
[1] "Petal.Width"  "Sepal.Length"
```

So now each XGBoost model is trained on a different combination of the iris variables.

Comment: For the `glm` model, I guess the data would be `df[, 1:4]`

Comment: I get an error `Error in predict.xgb.Booster(.x, newdata = as.matrix(dat), type = "prob") : 
  Feature names stored in `object` and `newdata` are different!`. Can you check the `features_list`

Comment: Could it be that the model is trained on `data = as.matrix(df[, 1:2])` and the `newdata` is `newdata = as.matrix(df[, 1:4])`?

Comment: There are only two columns in each of the data.frames in boundary_lists ` map_int(boundary_lists, ncol)
 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2`

Comment: The issue is that the 'df[1:2]` which was used for training columns are different i.e. `map_chr(boundary_lists, ~ toString(names(.x)))#
 [1] "Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length"  "Petal.Length, Sepal.Length" "Petal.Width, Sepal.Length"  "Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width" 
 [5] "Petal.Length, Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Width, Sepal.Width"   "Sepal.Length, Petal.Length" "Sepal.Width, Petal.Length" 
 [9] "Petal.Width, Petal.Length"  "Sepal.Length, Petal.Width"  "Sepal.Width, Petal.Width"   "Petal.Length, Petal.Width" 
''
> names(df)[1:2]
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"`

Comment: It needs to match the exact column names or else will fail

Comment: I see, you are right! Yes I have `data = as.matrix(df[, 1:2])` and `label = as.matrix(df[, 5])`. I need to create a new "training" list using `df_lists <- map2(
  .x = var_combos$Var1,
  .y = var_combos$Var2,
  ~select(df, .x, .y)
)` and then map the xgboost training model over these lists.

Comment: If you have the correct `boundary_lists`, the below solution would work.  `out3 <- map2(models_list, boundary_lists, ~ {
       mods <- pluck(.x, "models");
    dat <- .y;
    map(mods,  ~if(attr(.x, "class")[1] == "xgb.Booster") {
    NULL
       #tibble(modelname = attr(.x, "class")[1], 
       #  prediction = predict(.x, newdata = as.matrix(dat), type = 'prob')) 
          } else {
          tibble(modelname = attr(.x, "class")[1],
          prediction = predict(.x, newdata = dat))}   )   
    
    }  
    
    )`

Comment: The problem is on my side with the `xgboost` training data. The `glm` training data takes the form `glm(Species ~ ., data = .x...`, the `svm` model takes `svm(Species ~ ., data = .x...`. Where `.x` comes from the different lists (I added an edit). The `xgboost` model does not train on the 12 separate lists.

Comment: The edit is still giving the same error for me

Comment: I want to create 12 independent `xgboost` models (which has different combinations of the variables). Then I can map the `predict` function to each of the 12 lists in `boundary_data`.

Comment: I will try to fix this issue and come back to SO and edit the post with a working model.

Comment: okay, got, it.  the `models_list` needs changer

Comment: Yes, it needs changing to be trained on each of the 12 lists. Currently it is only being trained on `df[, 1:2]` which correspond to  `Sepal.Length` and `Sepal.Width` but in `model_lists` data (`models_list[[2]]$data`) for example the data corresponds to `Petal.Length` and `Sepal.Length` so the model breaks since it doesn't have the same columns as it was trained on. So I need 12 different trained `xgboost` models (as opposed to currently the 1 `xgboost` model trained on `df[, 1:2]`).

Comment: I added an EDIT which I think fixes the `models_list` part of the problem.

Comment: Now, it works.  Please check my update

Comment: Thanks! I have got it working. Is your update with or without the EDIT I made to the original post?

Comment: It is with the EDIT from your post.  I didn't have to change anything in that except added the `.id = 'grp'` at the end

Comment: Good. to know.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `attrs` "class" can extract the "class" and then we do a comparison with `if/else`

```
library(xgboost)
library(purrr)
```

If we are passing the corresponding `features_list` dataset for each element of 'models_list`, then use`map2` as outer most loop

```
out1 <- map2_dfr(models_list, boundary_lists, ~ {
       mods <- pluck(.x, "models")
       dat <- .y
       map_dfr(mods,  ~if(attr(.x, "class")[1] == "xgb.Booster") {

       tibble(modelname = attr(.x, "class")[1], 
         prediction = predict(.x, newdata = as.matrix(dat), type = 'prob')) 
          } else {
          tibble(modelname = attr(.x, "class")[1],
          prediction = predict(.x, newdata = dat))}   )   

       }, .id = 'grp' 

       )




head(out1)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  modelname prediction grp  
#  <chr>          <dbl> <chr>
#1 glm             1.95 1    
#2 glm             1.97 1    
#3 glm             1.98 1    
#4 glm             1.99 1    
#5 glm             2.00 1    
#6 glm             2.01 1
```

Comment: Thanks! this is working. Appologies though since the `newdata` was supposed to be each of the lists in `boundary_lists` and not `df[, 1:4]`. In the `models_predict` part of the code I use `map2` where `.y` is the `boundary_lists`. How can add in a `map` where the `newdata` is the `boundary_lists` list?

Comment: @user113156 I think the `map2` would be the outer one